# How to get git to not show certain files under untracked section in git status

Tags: git

When I type git status I have so many untracked files I can't even read the rest of my status output because it gets cut off in terminal. Is there a way to get certain file extensions not to show up as untracked under git status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the `.gitignore` file for this purpose. Create a file called `.gitignore` in your base directory, and add lines like

```
*.bak
*.out
```

for whatever kinds of files you want to ignore. You may also add and commit this `.gitignore` file to your repository, to easily share it with other users.

Comment: it doesn't do anything. the files still show up as untracked under git status.

Comment: Well it quite assuredly *does* do something. Here's the official documentation if you don't believe me: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html

Comment: I am not sure what the word "ignore" means to the git developers. I just want certain files not to show up under untracked when I type git status.

Comment: From the documentation: *The purpose of gitignore files is to ensure that certain files not tracked by git remain untracked.* So it is intended to do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: So it just stops you from being able to git add them ? thats not what I am looking for.

Comment: @user1086516 - `.gitignore` also hides untracked files in `git status`, just as you're expecting, make sure you're adding ignore rules properly.

Comment: You can still `git add <ignored_file>` if needed. The status will still report the change status of all tracked files even if they are in the .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

Use the .gitignore file

dir/* in there will hide all files in a directory
*.png should hide all png files

Answer (score 0):

Use .gitignore file and as Greg mentioned add *.extension where extension is the file extension you want git to exclude from your untracked files.
One more hint worth mentioning, suppose you want all *.txt files to be excluded but you do want readme.txt to be included then add two following lines in .gitignore:

*.txt
!readme.txt

Answer (score 0):

After you placed them in .gitignore, they still show up if they were in your tree before. Any new file of this type you add will not be shown.